# Audio Record and play loopback Issue

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am trying to do audio record and play simultaneously in my android application, The code working fine for the first time then it is crashing. giving the below error. Could any one please resolve this or suggest me the way to resolve this.

```
Error :
DALVIK THREADS:
    (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40022178 self=0xce48
      | sysTid=3508 nice=-19 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1345006496
      | schedstat=( 94146739 97717292 625 )
          at android.media.AudioTrack.native_write_byte(Native Method)
      at android.media.AudioTrack.write(AudioTrack.java:912)
      at com.brcm.factorymode.audioloop.speaker.RecordNPlay.loopback(RecordNPlay.java:102)
      at com.brcm.factorymode.audioloop.speaker.RecordNPlay$1.run(RecordNPlay.java:131)
      at com.brcm.factorymode.audioloop.speaker.RecordNPlay.do_loopback(RecordNPlay.java:136)
      at com.brcm.factorymode.audioloop.speaker.RecordNPlay.onCreate(RecordNPlay.java:53)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please check code used below suggest.

```
        public void loopback() {
            buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
            // Prepare the AudioRecord & AudioTrack
            Log.e("LOG", "Entered into loopback function....");

            try {

                buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Audio", "Buffer size failed");
            }

            if (buffersize <= BUF_SIZE) {
                buffersize = BUF_SIZE;
            }
            try {
                //findAudioRecord(); 
                m_record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                        SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize * 1);

                m_track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                        SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize * 1,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                m_track.setPlaybackRate(SAMPLE_RATE);
                Log.e("LOG", "INITIALIZATIONS DONE....");

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Audio", "Audio Failed");
            }
            if(m_record!=null)
            if (m_record.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                m_record.startRecording();
            if(m_track!=null)
            if (m_track.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                m_track.play();
            try {
                int i = 0;
                while (i<=10) {
                //  buffer=new byte[buffersize];
                    m_record.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                    m_track.write(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                    //m_track.flush();

    /*              try{
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    }catch(Exception e){}
    */              
                    i++;
                }
                if (i>10) {
                    buffer = null;
                        m_record.stop();
                    m_track.stop();
                    i=0;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Em_recordRROR", "exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            Log.i("D2Record", "loopback exit");
        }

        private void do_loopback() {

            m_thread = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
                    m_isRun = true;

                    loopback();

                }
            };

            m_thread.run();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved, The problem is in device source, I tested it in many other devices. it is working fine.

Comment: plz have a look on my question and help me in similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413998/live-audio-recording-and-playing-in-android