# Capture audio and send return

Tags: android

I need to create an application that captures the signal from the microphone and send directly to the headphone output.

Any idea?

Comment: Find examples for each task (recording and playback), understand them, and patch them together.  Even just the recording example has most of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to record and play audio simultaneously. Use [AudioRecord](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html&ei=r_JoUZ3zBIaGrAfw6YGoDw&usg=AFQjCNFBt26xiWEJRm08NKiIe-hLH_j3Kg&sig2=MNs0w2Yzr1IdzcE_-V8UUQ&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bmk) for recording and [AudioTrack](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html&ei=t_JoUeOlO4WQrgfo6oDoBA&usg=AFQjCNEZ1q9apedBkvGFgO8H8_lW3TImwg&sig2=iZ9ygcynP105ZRacQWoDYw&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bmk) for playing. you can find plenty of simultaneous play and recording example out there. Here are some sample links

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728454/playing-back-sound-coming-from-microphone-in-real-time), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959486/audio-record-and-play-loopback-issue)